# Add a computed property to a select prompt

Tags: ember.js

I'd like to render a prompt which reads "All products (500)". 500 being the total number of available products. `prompt="All products {{filteredProductsCount}}"` doesn't work.

What do I have to change to add the value of `filteredProductsCount` to the prompt?

**controller.js**

```
filteredProductsCount: function() {
  var filteredProducts = this.get('filteredProducts');
  return filteredProducts.length;
}.property('filteredProducts')
```

**template.hbs**

```
{{view "select" prompt="All products"
       content=filteredProducts
       value=selectedProduct
       class="form-control"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the prompt string as a computed property as well:

```
promptText: computed('filteredProductsCount', function() {
  // If you are using ES6
  return `All products ${this.get('filteredProductsCount')}`;
  // If not
  return 'All products ' + this.get('filteredProductsCount');
})
```

And in your template :

```
{{view "select" prompt=promptText
       content=filteredProducts
       value=selectedProduct
       class="form-control"}}
```

A few things you should watch out for, the `.property()` syntax is being deprecated in favor of `Ember.computed` and views are going away in ember 2.0, give [Future proofing Ember](https://gist.github.com/samselikoff/1d7300ce59d216fdaf97) a read.